# Determining an empty cell

Tags: scripting

I need help finding how to determining if a cell is empty.

At the moment i would use If(sheet.getRange("A2").getValue() == 0) {

But this is now causing issues if the cell actually contains the value 0 and is not empty. therefore my question is how do i make my script see if the cell is empty.

PS i'm new to all this.

Comment: I don't know what language you use, but it is not Java at all

Answer (score 0):

use `If(sheet.getRange("A2").getValue() == NULL)`